# Date Format(YYYY-MM-DD) in DatePicker and Date field

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I have a date field in my application. By clicking it, a calendar appears. So after selecting a date, the date field must be shown as 'YYYY-MM-DD' but it shows as 'MM-DD-YYYY'.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="from">From</label>
    <div class="input-group " >         
        <span class="add-on input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
        <input id="startdate" name="startdate" type="date">         
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="to">To</label>
    <div class="input-group " >
        <span class="add-on input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
        <input id="enddate" name="enddate"  type="date">
    </div>          
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#startdate,#enddate').datepicker({dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Replace your `dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"` with `dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"`

Answer (score 1):

Change the `yyyy` to `yy`. Here you have the doc http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Comment: No.Same thing happening.

Comment: I dont Know. Even i copied your code and tested. Same thing. It shows as mm/dd/yyyy. Is there anything i want to do in datepicker.js, Because im including that in my header.php as <script src="<?=BASE_URL?>js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script> and  <link href="<?=BASE_URL?>css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Ok, I already know what is going on here. You are using the `bootstrap-datepicker` but you use the `jquery-ui` `datepicker` API to configure it. Just change `dateFormat` to `format` and it will work. Here you have the correct documentation https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score -1):

In my experience format of the date depends on language which set for browser.
In browser js console you can see it with

```
navigator.languages
```

Hope it helps.